# how to remove one data in r

Tags: r

In R I have some vector.

```
x <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
```

I want to remove only "0" in x vector, but it removes all '0' in this vector.
Example

```
x=x[!x %in% 0 )]
```

All zero in this vector had been remove in x vector

For Example in Python

```
x = [0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]
x.remove(0)
x
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
x.remove(0)
x
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: 1) You have an extra comma in your x vector at the end (2) you are missing an open parenthesis in `x` = x[!(x %in% 0)]` (3) What is your expected output?

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: Thank's. I copy my code in project and edit some variable to short for this questions. this code in here are incorrect. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Can you please remove the python tag? This is not a question regarding Python and you barely touch the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `match` to remove the first occurrence of a particular number

```
x <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
x[-match(1, x)] 

#[1] 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

If you have any other number to remove in array, for example 5 in the case below,

```
x <- c(1, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 1)
x[-match(5, x)]
#[1] 1 0 5 0 0 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need `which.min()`,

> which determines the index of the first minimum of a vector:

```
x <- c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1)
x <- x[-which.min(x)]
x
# [1] 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

If your vector contains elements other than 0 or 1: `x <- x[-which.min(x != 0)]`